# is it legal to make my own database and use with google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a project which requires me to make my own database of a large number of clinics. these clinics will be shown on google maps. some of these clinics are already displayed by google while many others are not. I plan to make a new database of all the clinics on my own server and these clinics will then be displayed on google maps which I am using in my application. Is this legal If I do so ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question that should be directed to Google support and/or the posted licenses.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Google have an [**article**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) which uses PHP/MySQL to generate XML for use in Google Maps.

See a demo I have created using my own database [**here**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php)